# This is how/what he likes his soup – hot and spicy

Tags: wh-questions

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/this-is-how-he-likes-his-soup.3857459/):
**(1a)** *This is **how** he likes his soup – hot and spicy*.
It's said there (1a) is correct. But if I didn't know it, I would think it's incorrect, because when I met "*how*" it made me begin expecting that further in the sentence there would be some adverbial phrase which "*how*" is referring to, but then I suddenly saw the adjectives "hot and spicy" (instead of an adverbial phrase) and so was immediately very confused, because with adjectives I thought we must use "*what*" rather than "*how*".

To deal with it, I decided to compare "how" and "what" in this sentence. For this purpose, I made up several variants. Could you tell me please which of the next ones are correct and which are not and why?:

**(1b)** *This is **what** he likes his soup – hot and spicy*.

**(2a)** *This is **how** he likes his soup – he locks himself in the kitchen and won't let anyone in until he's eaten it all*.
**(2b)** *This is **what** he likes his soup – he locks himself in the kitchen and won't let anyone in until he's eaten it all*.

**(3a)** *This is **how** he likes his soup – to salt a little and sprinkle with herbs*.
**(3b)** *This is **what** he likes his soup – to salt a little and sprinkle with herbs*.

**(4a)** *This is **how** he likes his soup – the way that no one else does*.
**(4b)** *This is **what** he likes his soup – the way that no one else does*.

**(5a)** *This is **how** he likes his soup – very-very much*.
**(5b)** *This is **what** he likes his soup – very-very much*.

Comment: Can't resist: This is what he likes **in his soup**.

Comment: @Lambie - **that** is **not** what I like in **my** soup (I couldn't resist either).

Answer (score 2):

I can see your logic, but no, it's "how" every time.

The gap in your knowledge is that "how" does not only replace manner, but also quality.

> — How was the trip you mentioned?
>
> — It was amazing!

"What" replaces a noun phrase.

> — What was the trip you mentioned?
>
> — It was a school trip to Quebec!

It can also replace a verbal clause.

> — What did you think of the trip?
>
> — I thought it was exciting!

Comment: **What** is the table? The table is **black**. - correct. **How** is the table? - incorrect. Why do these examples go by other rules? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii They don't go by other rules. "How" is correct and "what" is incorrect there too. I don't know where you learned otherwise.

Comment: "What is the table **like**?" is a valid sentence, "What is the table?" isn't (unless the speaker didn't know what a table is!).

Comment: @Loviii you can say "What *color* is the table?" but not "What is the table?"